# IDLEに出力する際のテキストエディタに記載するprint()の件

Tags: python, python3

Python始めたばかりで初歩的な質問ですみません。

テキストエディタに書いたプログラムからIDLEに出力する際に、

```
print（変数や文字列など）
```

としないとIDLE側で出力できないと思っていましたが、
とある書籍のプログラム例（古くからあるハングマンというゲーム）で
printの記載がなくてもIDLEでプログラムを走らせることができました。

具体的には、テキストエディタのプログラムの最後が

```
hangman("cat")
```

となっており、ゲームが終了するとIDLEのウィンドウに

```
>>> cat
```

と出力されます。

`print(hangman("cat"))` としても cat と出ますが、

```
>>> cat
>>> None
```

と、’None'が一緒に出てきました。

これまで勉強してきたコードではテキストエディタでprintをつけないと、
IDLEでの出力がエラーは出ずに空白の出力になっていたので、
テキストエディタにprint〜と記載しないとダメだとおもっていましたが、
何が起こっているのでしょうか。教えてください。

**対象のプログラム**

```py
def hangman(word): 
    wrong=0 
    stages=["", 
            "________ ",
            "|        ", 
            "|    |   ", 
            "|    O   ", 
            "|   /|\  ", 
            "|   / \  ", 
            "|        " 
            ] 
    rletters=list(word) 
    board=["_ "]*len(word) 
    win=False 
    print("ハングマンへようこそ！！")
    while wrong<len(stages)-1: 
        print("\n") 
        msg="文字を予想してね:" 
        char=input(msg) 
        if char in rletters:
            cind=rletters.index(char)   
            board[cind]=char 
            rletters[cind]='$' 
        else: 
            wrong+=1 
        print("".join(board)) 
        e=wrong+1 
        print("\n".join(stages[0:e]))
        if "_ " not in board: 
            print("あなたの勝ち！！") 
            print("".join(board)) 
            win=True 
            break
    if not win:
        print("\n".join(stages[0:wrong+1])) 
        print("あなたの負け！正解は{}。".format(word)) 

hangman("cat")
```

Comment: 「hangman()」は関数のようですがその実装はどうなっていますか？hangmanの中でprint()が使われていませんか？

Comment: @merino さま
返信ありがとうございます。確認遅なり申し訳ありません。hangman()はおっしゃる通り関数になっています。以下の通りです。
長いので、３回に 分けて返信します。
def hangman(word):
    wrong=0
  stages=["",
                 "________     ",
                 "|                    ",
                 "|              |     ",
                 "|             O    ",
                 "|             /|\    ",
                 "|             / \    ",
                 "|                    "
                 ]
    rletters=list(word)
    board=["_ "]*len(word)
    win=False
    print("ハングマンへようこそ！！")

続く

Comment: while wrong<len(stages)-1:
        print("\n")
        msg="文字を予想してね:"
        char=input(msg)
        if char in rletters:
            cind=rletters.index(char)
            board[cind]=char
            rletters[cind]='$'
        else:
            wrong+=1
        print("".join(board))
        e=wrong+1
        print("\n".join(stages[0:e]))
        if "_ " not in board:
            print("あなたの勝ち！！")
            print("".join(board))
            win=True
            break

続く

Comment: if not win:
        print("\n".join(stages[0:wrong+1]))
        print("あなたの負け！正解は{}。".format(word))
hangman("cat")

printが使われてる箇所は何箇所かありますが、その場合は、不要になるということでそうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `hangman()`関数はコメントではなく質問に追加する形で記述願います。
それと, 「エディター」とは何を指しますか？ IDLEのエディター？ それも VS Codeなどの一般的なテキストエディター？

Comment: エディタは一般的なテキストエディタです。関数は質問の追加しておきます。

Comment: プログラムを質問に追記しましたが、改行位置と空白が上手く表示されていないかもしれません。(打ち込んだ時は正しく入れたのですが)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hangman("cat")
> となっており、ゲームが終了するとIDLEのウィンドウに
> ＞＞＞cat

関数hangmanの中でprint()が呼ばれている（使われている）ためhangman()を呼ぶと`cat`が出力されます。

> print(hangman("cat"))としてもcatと出ますが、
> ＞＞＞cat
> ＞＞＞None
> と、’None'が一緒に出てきました。

その`cat`は`hangman`の中で出力されているものです。また。`None`は`hangman`の戻り値が出力されているものです。（戻り値が設定されていない関数の場合`None`が返ります。）

Comment: @merinoさま　ありがとうございます。関数内でprintが使われていれば，最後は関数名で良いと言うことですね。Noneが出る意味もわかりました。

Answer (score 2):

コマンドラインから `python` (もしくは環境によっては `py` など) で起動すると インタープリターが起動し, [対話モード(Interactive Mode)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode) になります
いくつか指定した場合(一挙にコピペしたときなど), 最後に指定した分の結果が表示(print)されます
(対話モードかどうかは 三つの「大なり記号」 (`>>>`) で判別可能)

(Pythonに限らず)このようなモードは, REPL (Read-Eval-Print Loop) とも呼ばれます
参考: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL

`idle` はその tkinter GUI 版 (というだけ)

```py
Python 3.10.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Aug 22 2022, 20:36:39) [GCC 10.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1+1
2
>>> def fn(s):
...   return 'hello ' + s
...
>>> fn('world')
'hello world'
```

---

【追記】

組み込み関数 [`print`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#print) を呼び出しても表示されるし, 対話モードの「大なり記号」 (`>>>`) を使った(計算などの)結果も表示されます。
ある関数(この場合 `hangman`)内で組み込み関数 `print`が利用されていれば, その場合も表示されるでしょう

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。確認が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
idleがtkinterということはよく分りました。参考URLもありがとうございます。
よくわからないのは、idle上で短いコマンドを>>>に入れて実行する場合は
>>>1+1
→出力：2
となりますが、テキストエディタ上では
print(1+1)
として実行しないと、idleで「2」と表示されなかったので、
テキストエディタ上ではprintと必ずしないとダメかと思っていました。
テキストエディタ上でprintと表記しなくてもよいパターンはあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 「テキストエディタ上でprintと表記しなくてもよいパターン」というのはよく意味がわかりません

Comment: 表現が悪くて申し訳ありません。「表記しなくていいパターン」とは今回質問させていただいた一般的なテキストエディタでidleに出力される際に、printと書かない場合ことです。ご回答いただいた、関数内でprintが記載されていれば、最後に関数名だけ記載すれば出力されるということが理解できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: もしも問題が解決しているのなら [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) を参考にどうぞ。質問の中でまだ未解決のところがあるなら, (質問文更新とか追記するなどで)明確にすると良いかも